# Why is SBT NOT excluding these libraries despite using excludes?

Tags: sbt

Despite doing the following, sbt is still grabbing lift-json. Why?

```
"net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % "2.6-M4" % "compile" excludeAll(ExclusionRule("net.liftweb", "lift-json"))
```

More info. This is what dependency tree shows:

```
+-net.liftweb:lift-mapper_2.10:2.6-M4
[info]   | +-net.liftweb:lift-db_2.10:2.6-M4
[info]   | | +-net.liftweb:lift-util_2.10:2.6-M4
[info]   | | | | 
…
[info]   | | | |   
[info]   | | | +-net.liftweb:lift-json_2.10:2.6-M4
```

So dependency is lift-mapper -> lift-db -> lift-util -> lift-json, perhaps exclusion is not deep?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The key thing here that's not obvious is that exclusions in sbt are really just pass-through rules for the underlying Ivy engine. Since Ivy knows nothing about sbt conventions (for instance, appending `_2.10` to dependencies that are Scala release specific), you need to tell it what it should really be excluding. In this case, that means the line should look like this:

```
"net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % "2.6-M4" % "compile" excludeAll(ExclusionRule("net.liftweb", "lift-json_2.10"))
```

Perhaps there is some enhancement that can be made to sbt to allow it to see that since the dependency you've defined is Scala release specific, it should also try adding the exclusion rule for that release, as well.

Comment: Yea. I've ran into this too. Could either you or @ChanningWalton open a Github issue for it please?

Comment: It is possible to exclude scala dependency without hardcoding it's scala version:
excludeAll(ExclusionRule("net.liftweb", "lift-json").withCrossVersion(CrossVersion.binary))

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps there are some other libraries depend on it. You can find those libs by using the [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin. Or simply exclude it from all the dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ......
).map(_.excludeAll(ExclusionRule("net.liftweb", "lift-json")))
```

Comment: I use dependency graph to check, and the only place lift-json is coming from is lift-mapper.

Comment: if excluding from libraryDependencies does not work try the same with allDependencies

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is required to fix transitive dependency problems!