# SBT transitive dependency resolution conflict

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, ivy, dependency-resolution

I have a problem in SBT resolving transitive dependencies.

The error is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vividsolutions.jts.index.strtree.STRtree.queryBoundary()Ljava/util/List
```

`Geospark` is using `jts2geojson` `https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jts2geojson/blob/master/pom.xml` which references jts in version `1.14`, but this is excluded and they use a custom artifact as a replacement. It is called `JTSPlus` which still lives in the `com.vividsolutions` namespace and provides some additional methods, i.e. the one which is missing above.

The latest `geotools 17` is using `jts` in version `1.13`
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/pom.xml#L752-L754

I need to **replace `com.vividsolution.jts` from geotools with `org.datasyslab.jtsplus`** which offers additional but required functionality how can I achieve this?

In maven:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org. geotools </groupId>
            <artifactId> geotools </artifactId>
            <version>YOURVERSION</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

should work, but for SBT using

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.geotools" % "gt-main" % geotools,
  "org.geotools" % "gt-arcgrid" % geotools,
  "org.geotools" % "gt-process-raster" % geotools)
  .map(_.excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.vividsolution", artifact = "jts")
  ))
```

did not fix it. Actually, whe using the dependencyGraph, I can see SBT is still applying the regular jts in version 1.13 to the whole project.

**How can I fix the dependencies to properly exclude the original JTS version?**

My build.sbt looks like

```
lazy val geotools = "17.0"

resolvers += "osgeo" at "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools"
resolvers += "boundless" at "http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main"
resolvers += "imageio" at "http://maven.geo-solutions.it"
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.geotools" % "gt-main" % geotools,
  "org.geotools" % "gt-arcgrid" % geotools,
  "org.geotools" % "gt-process-raster" % geotools)
  .map(_.excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "com.vividsolution", artifact = "jts")
  ))

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.datasyslab" % "geospark" % "0.6.1-snapshot"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Why is SBT NOT excluding these libraries despite using excludes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179314/why-is-sbt-not-excluding-these-libraries-despite-using-excludes) mentioned in the comments that `allDependencies` instead of `libraryDependencies` needs to be used. I think this is required due to the transitive problems.